# Why class level attributes work with Null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, class-attributes

I would think the following would throw NullPointerException

```
class N { 
    static int i;
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 
        System.out.println( ((N)null).i );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Because `i` is static (class level) member. It exists for class, for every object of it. So it really doesn't require reference to object, so this part `((N)null)` is actually ignored, except for type inference. It could and should be replaced with `N.i`.